# How many coins will be available after bitcoin cash fork?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, blockchain-fork

I am confused about bitcoin cash fork.

Will Bitcoin Cash disappear and its name change to the Bitcoin cash ABC? or after hash war there will be only one coin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be one additional coin after the fork. One network will keep the ticker BCH and the other will get a new one. At the moment it looks like ABC is going to keep the BCH ticker and Bitcoin SV will get the ticker BSV.

The fork is much the same as previous forks off of BTC. The coin with the most proof of work gets to keep the ticker symbol. Right now ABC chain has 55% more PoW done than SV chain.